# Angular 2+ pipe and material tooltip

Tags: angular

I would like to get some recommandation.

I got a model

[{value:n , user:userId}], value can be 0,1,2 etc...

at first client was receiving an array with a list of object {value: 0, user: A}  {value: 1, user: B}  {value: 0, user: C}. I couldn't get something like {value: 0, users [A,C]}, value:1, users: [B] } in order to get something like this : Icon (corresponding to this value)  - counting (number of people having this value) - Tooltip with list of user for this value

So I created a pipe to transform the array to [{value = n, users=[list UserId]}]

Problem is : 
- Pipe is called like 1000 times instead of 5
- Tooltip (matTooltip, material design) is not working.

Is there another solution than using a pipe without changing my model as I like the way it is for flexibility purpose ?

Comment: first - please demonstrate your problem with stackblitz demo(like https://stackblitz.com/angular/rmdkeavlyxr). second - as far as i know pipes are not better way to transform data. instead i recommend to use native 'map' method

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help:

```
  const finalObject = [{value: 0, user: 'A'} ,{value: 1, user: 'B'},{value: 1, user: 'C'}].reduce((ag, item)=>{

  ag[item.value] = ag[item.value]+1 || 1;    
  return ag;

},{});
// {0:1, 1:2}
```

Comment: Just found the solution, my pipe pure argument was set to false (I misunderstood the action of this argument) Thanks for your answer I will probably see to use it instead of my method into my pipe as it seems more elegant. I dunno the complexity behind it.